# NSTimer in Swift and Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nstimer

in this scenario, what difference in this code :

OBJ-C :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(start) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[self start];
}
```

in Obj-C this code work smoothly, and i use similar code using Swift like this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var myTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: Selector(start()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(myTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)


    start()
}
```

but have error after 5 sec, and no clue what error exactly, just EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code= 1, address=0x0)

what am i missing?

Comment: i think the problem is in Start method.

Comment: can you please explain what is in "start" method in selector

Comment: You should use `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` instead of `timerWithTimeInterval` without `start`

Comment: obj c style Selector is no longer needed when you are on swift.

Comment: just function to get data from database. the point purpose using timer is if you input new data, otomatically after 5 sec it will show, but if no new data incoming, is not loop because i debug at obj-c its not running always 5sec. this obj-c work smoothly, no error

Comment: @iphonic , so in swift dont use NSTimer(timerInterval ...) but use NSTimer.scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval(time,target,selector,userinfo,repeats)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let myTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: "start", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(myTimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

func start() {
    print("Fired")
}
```

Comment: its works, so in swift no need Selector(start()), great info. thx man

Comment: Just want to point out the difference between `Selector(start())`, `Selector("start")`, `"start"`. First one is getting the return value of start as the selector, second one is correct and it gets the reference id of start from the objc runtime, the third is implicit, also correct, and is bridged to call NSSelectorFromString.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)setupTimer {
    NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(onTick:)
                                                userInfo:nil 
                                                 repeats:NO];  

}

- (void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer {
// Put your code here
}
```

Comment: Please, provide explanation.

Comment: It is timer with object "t" with time interval 2.0 sec and it will call method  ( onTick:) once  because repeat set to "NO" if it 'YES"  then it will call  method every 2.0 seconds repetitively.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (Swift 3+) use always native `Timer`, the `scheduledTimer` API and – whenever possible – the block based API

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5.0, repeats: true) { timer in
       // do something
    } 
}
```

And if you are using the target / action based API use Swift `#selector` syntax and put the action method out of `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(start), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
} 

@objc func start(_ timer: Timer) {
    // do something
}
```